# Jquery selector next element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there is a way to select every next element (nested or not) ?
Example :

```
<div class="div1">
   <span class="span2">span1</span>

   <div class="div2">
        <span class="span2">span2</span>
   </div>

   <span id="current_span">current span></span>

   <span class="span2">span3</span>

   <div class="div2">
        <span class="span2">span4</span>
   </div>

</div>
```

I would like to do something like it :

```
$("#current_span").[select_every_next_item_with_span2_class].hide();
```

`span3` / `span4` hidden

And

```
$("#current_span").[select_every_prev_item_with_span2_class].show();
```

`span1` / `span2` visible

Comment: [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Comment: and **[`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)**

Comment: It's always worth just reading through the method listing at http://api.jquery.com every once in a while. Most method names are very descriptive and even without clicking on their description should give you a good idea of what they do. tl;dr RTFM ;)

Comment: I edited question because i was maybe ambigious, on my exemple, i need span1/span2 with prev selection. prevAll give me only span1

Comment: @A.Rossi This is because your span2 is not a sibling of the current_span. It is the niece of it (the sibling is div2, and span2 is the daughter of div2).

Comment: That's why i ask this question, i need a way to sibling prev nested element from current element.

Comment: @A.Rossi See my edited answer.

Comment: @A.Rossi I added an answer for you, as `nextAll()` and `prevAll()` are not suited for your specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with jQuery's [nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [prevAll()](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) functions.

For your code, this would be:

```
$("#current_span").nextAll().hide();
$("#current_span").prevAll().hide();
```

And as always, you can traverse the items in the list from the functions if you wish to do something separate with specific ones (i.e. use the [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function).

EDIT:
If you want to select the child elements of the siblings as well, you can do:

```
$("#current_span").nextAll().children().andSelf().hide();
```

This selects both the siblings and the children of the siblings.

I also added a code snippet to show you how this can work with your code. Click on `currentspan1` to toggle the top two elements and `currentspan2` to toggle the bottom two.

```js
$("#current_span1").click(function(){
  $(this).prevAll().toggle();
});

$("#current_span2").click(function(){
  $(this).nextAll().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <span class="span2">span1</span>

  <div class="div2">
    <span class="span2">span2</span>
  </div>

  <span id="current_span1">current span1</span> <br>
  <span id="current_span2">current span2</span> <br>

  <span class="span2">span3</span>

  <div class="div2">
    <span class="span2">span4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited question because i was maybe ambigious, on my exemple, i need span1/span2 with prev selection. prevAll give me only span1

Comment: Worth noting that nextAll and prevAll only traverse sibling elements, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextAll()` to get all next siblings and then traverse each one for the elements you need.

```
$("#current_span").nextAll().each(function () {
       if ($(this).is(".span2")) { 
           $(this).hide();
       }
       $(this).find(".span2").hide();
});
$("#current_span").prevAll().each(function () {
       if ($(this).is(".span2")) { 
           $(this).show();
       }
       $(this).find(".span2").show();
});
```

Fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/tq3ubLap/

Comment: I edited question because i was maybe ambigious, on my exemple, i need span1/span2 with prev selection. prevAll give me only span1

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all the previous/next `.span2` elements, regardless of their relationship to the current `.span2` you could use `index('.span2')` to get their index within the scope of the document. From there you can use `slice()` to retrieve the required elements. Try this:

```js
$('.span2').click(function() {
 var $spans = $('.span2');
 var index = $(this).index('.span2');
    var $prev = $spans.slice(0, index);
    var $next = $spans.slice(index + 1);
    
    // for demo purposes only
    $('.span2').removeClass('next prev');
    $prev.addClass('prev');
    $next.addClass('next');
});
```

```css
.prev {
    background-color: #C00;
    color: #FFF;
}
.next {
    background-color: #CC0;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
    <span class="span2">span1</span>

    <div class="div2">
        <span class="span2">span2</span>
    </div>

    <span id="current_span">current span></span>

    <span class="span2">span3</span>

    <div class="div2">
        <span class="span2">span4</span>
    </div>
</div>
```